# How do I open a new git bash terminal window at my current location in windows?

Tags: windows, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, git

When running git bash, I can open a new bash window at my root with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

I can open a windows explorer window at the current directory path

```
$ explorer .
```

Trying

```
$ sh
```

to open a new terminal window at my location just returns

```
sh: __git_ps1: command not found
```

and opens the shell in the current window without git running.

How can I quickly open a new bash shell at my location?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: @Biswapriyo MINGW64, GNU bash, version 4.4.12(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

Comment: The feature that you've requested is available from mintty 2.8.5 which is not added in git-for-windows latest release. So wait for future release.

Comment: @Biswapriyo looking into running `$ mintty`, I can add "git-bash.exe" to my path and run `$ git-bash` to do exactly what I want

Comment: @Biswapriyo My version of git-bash now ships with mintty 3.1.0. Do you happen to know how to enable the feature? Ideally with Alt-F2 or other shortcut (say I already have a task running, that I do not want to interrupt or put in the background)

Answer (score 12):

StuperUser answer is correct, but I want to add that besides adding shell script in a PATH environment it's also possible to add a simple bash alias into `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files.

Just create alias:

```
alias git-bash='/git-bash.exe & > /dev/null 2&>1'
```

bashrc and bash_profile it's a standard BASH configuration files, you can found them in your user home folder.

More information [Bash startup files](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-bashrc.html)

Answer (score 7):

Since this is specifically for a git-bash terminal, add the Git directory (C:\Program Files\Git) to your path (https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Then run

```
$ git-bash
```

to open a new git-bash at the current location.

But to avoid blocking the current terminal it will be necessary to use `& > /dev/null 2&>1` to run in the background and pipe the result into null (see https://superuser.com/a/1314830/641), so added the command to a .sh in the directory to call it simply.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a couple years old, but I wanted to post this anyways.

When I use @Alex's answer, it seems like each window is attached to the other through linked processes or something. Here is my solution for completely independent new windows that start at the current location.

```
alias new='start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"'
```

That will get you one new window every time you use it. But I actually like to have 4 terminals open, so I typically use the following alias to open 3 new terminal windows at the current location:

```
alias new3='start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" && start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" && start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Set the environmental variable pointing to git location `C:\Program Files\Git`.

Now go to your location in windows where you wanna open git bash.

Press `alt + d` and type `get-bash` and you are good to go.