# How to stop git-bash shell from waiting for process to finish?

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, git-bash

Based on a solution to [How do I open a new git bash terminal window at my current location in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1314743/how-do-i-open-a-new-git-bash-terminal-window-at-my-current-location-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment1956775_1314743) I can use

```
$ git-bash
```

to launch a new terminal from inside a git-bash console window.

However, this will block the original terminal which will be waiting for the result of the new git-bash.

Can I start a new terminal window without having it wait for the result?

Comment: Can you try `git-bash & > /dev/null 2&>1`?

Comment: @slhck Nice, I've added that as a .sh in the Git folder that's in my path and using that, if you add that as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash, you can append `&` to run a command in the background.

In order to suppress its shell output (if any), you can also redirect its STDERR and STDOUT to `/dev/null`.

So, use this:

```
git-bash & > /dev/null 2>&1
```

When you close the window, the command should also exit in the background.

Comment: Needs to read `git-bash & > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: I can't edit as it would be under 6 characters :|  I think I don't have enough rep yet

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it just said something like "Edits must be more than 6 characters.  Can you change something else?".  And I didn't want to make random changes so I left a comment instead :)  Would be good to have a feature to trial your account as a low rep user so you could see what I was talking about :)

Comment: @AJP I remember that character restriction now that you've mentioned it – it's probably not such a bad idea. It's hard to keep all the minor rules in mind when you're not participating as much anymore as I used to.  Anyway, thanks for your input!